# Missing DLL even though the directory containing it is in the path

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, dll, vtk

I'm currently trying to build and run some of the example of the VTK. Building goes just fine, however when trying to run the examples I have some missing DLLs errors. 
I am using windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2012.
My path actually include the directory where all the dlls are stored. The dlls are stored in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\bin\
```

My path value is:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Users\Lonni\Dev Utilities\gluegen\gluegen-2.3-b858-20150410-windows-amd64\gluegen-2.3-b858-20150410-windows-amd64\jar\gluegen-rt.jar;C:\Users\Lonni\Dev Utilities\jogl-2.3-b1392-20150410-windows-amd64\jogl-2.3-b1392-20150410-windows-amd64\jar\atomic\jogl.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1-VS9.0.30729-x64-release-12741\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\bin\
```

I first thought a typo was in my path and I have found a missing ";". But now that it's corrected it is still not working and I still get the missing dll error when trying to run my program.

Any help would be appreciated on that matter.

EDIT: Finally I had it wrong, now when I try to launch the exe file directly without VS it works just fine. However, when trying to launch it from within VS I get the DLL error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VStudio, go to your application project properties, select *Debugging*, and in the *Environment* option, add `PATH=%path_to_the_folder_where_your_your_dll_is_located%;` (I'd suggest using relative paths).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying this ASAP. Why do you suggest using relative paths btw?

Comment: For example your app is the result of building a VisualStudio project. If your needed dll is also a VisualStudio project (and the 2 project are linked together in the solution), and your app Project is located let's say under `C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\MyApp` set `PATH` to `..\Bin` rather to the full `C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\bin`.

Comment: Oh I see, yes of course you are completely right. Thanks a lot. Clear and correct instructions. Definitely deserved the +1 ;)